# How to submit a Firefox web-extension to their Store without giving a public access to it?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I tried to submit my web-extension (actually developed for Chrome) to the Mozilla Firefox Add-On Store but failed. I didn't find a privacy option (in the Chrome Extensions store it's possible to do this) which allows me to hide my extension there so that it could be accessible only by a desired link, so I published my extension there and set the Experimental option. But, it was rejected with the following reason:

> Due to the limited/non-public audience of this add-on, this add-on is not suitable for being listed. Please submit a self-hosted version and distribute the signed file yourself. Fore more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution

In other words, I want that my extension will be hidden in the Mozilla store and my users could download and install it only if I share a link with them.

Does anybody know how to do this? Because, as far as I can see I can do this as the [Self-distributed (unlisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution)) version but in this case, I need to share this signed version by myself as the .xpi file. The main problem in this approach is that I'll need to send updated versiona to them as well, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You have to submit your extension to the AMO in order to be signed. Here, the work of Firefox is ended and you have to manage your own extension. Check this for [reference](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/01/26/mixing-listed-and-unlisted-on-amo/), it is the most updated doc I could find for this.

Note that, you have to specify in your manifest how the extension will be updated. Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Updates).

Then, you can host it in your own server and provide a link to your users.

I haven't test the above, so proceed with caution.